# ArrayList returns last item for all entries

Tags: java, arraylist

I am trying to populate an ArrayList with objects to pass to an ArrayAdapter (eventually).  I have pulled out some code into a small test project to illustrate the issue.

I have a class called Rules which has two members, Gender and Age (Rules.Java).  In the class MyArrayTest I am creating instances of Rules objects and adding them to the rule_parts ArrayList.  When I loop over the Array the loop executes the expected number of times but duplicates the last element.  Please could someone point out why.

Rules.Java

```
public class Rules {
public static String Gender;
public static Integer Age;


public Rules(String G, Integer C) {
//super();
    Gender = G;
    Age = C;
    }
}
```

Main Class - MyArrayTest.java

```
import java.util.ArrayList;


public class MyArrayTest {


private static ArrayList<Rules> rule_parts = new ArrayList<Rules>();

public static void main(String[] args) {


// Rules Array  
rule_parts.add(new Rules("Male",25));
rule_parts.add(new Rules("Female",22));

System.out.printf("\n\nRules:\n\n");
for (Rules r : rule_parts) {
    System.out.printf (r.Gender + "\n");
    System.out.printf(r.Age + "\n");


    }

}

}
```

Output is as follows:

Rules:

Female
22

Female
22

Comment: Remove the `static` keyword from your class variables. As you have it right now you have defined 'global' state - the values in the class will always be whatever you last set them too, for ***all*** instances of the class. In general, do not make any of your class variables static unless you know what you're doing and have a *very* good reason for doing so.

Comment: In addition to what Perception has said: you seem to have totally misunderstood what `static` does. Please go through a Java tutorial to understand that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to make `Gender` and `Age` non-`static` otherwise these fields will only retain a single value per class member variable:

```
public String gender;
public Integer age;
```

*Aside:* Java naming conventions indicate that variables start with *lowercase* letters making  `Gender` `gender`, etc.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that your data members are `static`:

```
public static String Gender;
public static Integer Age;
```

This means that they are shared by all instances of the class.

Remove the `static` keywords and you'll be good to go.

Answer (score 1):

Issue is the static variables in rules class. Remove the static keyword. Static variables are instatiated per class. So it always takes the latest value

Comment: Thanks tmfor all your replies. In my application I originally had the members  non-static but eclipse wouldn't  build the project without setting these as static. I have revisited the Java  documentation and see the error  now .  Note that this code did build ok  previously but I have recently rebuilt my dev machine and it stopped working as expected at that point. I will update the code and re-post if it is still failing.