# I always get the last value of an ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist

Please read the post before marking it as duplicate.

and I am not a Java expert

This is a simplified code of what I am trying to do:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Parameter {

    private static ArrayList<Integer> quantityArray = new ArrayList<>();

    public static void quantityPriorityValues() {
        int q = 0 ;
        for (int i = 0; i < 5 ; i++ ) {
            quantityArray.add(q);
            q++;
        }
    }

    public static ArrayList<Integer> getQuantityArray() {
        return quantityArray;
    }

    public void setQuantityArray(ArrayList<Integer> quantityArray) {
         this.quantityArray = quantityArray;
    }
}

public class Connection {

    public void getParameters () {
        i = 0;    
     Parameter.quantityPriorityValues();

        while (i < 5) {

            int quantity = Parameter.getQuantityArray().get(i);
            System.out.println(quantity);
            i++;

        }
    }

}
```

It always prints out the last value of the arraylist. 
I checked answers about this problem , like this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19843506/why-does-my-arraylist-contain-n-copies-of-the-last-item-added-to-the-list) and this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15455735/arraylist-returns-last-item-for-all-entries) and they both said that the problem in in the `static`fields.So I tried to remove the `static` from `ArrayList<Integer> quantityArray` but that means that the getters and setters should be `non-static` too and I won't be able to call the getter in the `Connection` class.

I want this output: 0 1 2 3 4

But I get this output: 4

Does anyone have another solution?

Comment: Can you please add the expected output and the one that you get?

Comment: Please include your main method, so we can see where you initialize the list.

Comment: Indeed - ideally, rewrite this as a [mcve].

Comment: @StepTNT I edited my question

Comment: @Eran : In reality those two classes are JDialog classes and In my main method I just create a new instance of the class and set it as visible.

Comment: I added the output and the expected out so that you can see better my problem.

Comment: Please show your main-method. It seems that you overwrite your list somewhere

Comment: @Supahupe : I have nothing about the lists in the main method and as I said to Eran  "In reality those two classes are JDialog classes and In my main method I just create a new instance of the class and set it as visible."

Comment: before retrieving the elements, just try to print the arraylist `System.out.println(quantityArray);`, that will help in debugging

Comment: This is all nice, but now do, what Jon Skeet suggested. Thank you :).

Comment: @piyushjaiswal : yes I have already done that and the elements in the arrayList are perfectly correct. My problem is in the elements' retrieving.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your getParameters() function
Create an ArrayList like :

```
ArrayList<Integer> quantityArray = Parameters.getQuantityArray();
```

You can change your while loop like :

```
for (Integer i : quantityArray)
    System.out.println(i);
```

It should work